# how can I fix this Error loading ASGI app. Import string "src.main.app" must be in format "<module>:<attribute>"

Tags: docker

I am trying to build a docker image and once I try to run the app its producing this error. Below is the code in the VS

```
From python:3.10-slim
WORKDIR /code
COPY  ./requirement.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirement.txt
COPY ./src ./src
CMD ["uvicorn"," uvicorn.src.main.app", "--host","0.0.0.0", "--port","90","--reload"]***
```

Answer (score 0):

the line should be just like that in the form `<module>:<attribute>`, where the `attribute` is instance of an ASGI `app` it should refer to

```bash
CMD ["uvicorn", "src.main:app" ...
```